# Unable to load javascript files in express

Tags: javascript, express

I am making an express web app and I am unable to import a javascript file.

In `board.js`, I have a line `const utility = require('./utility');`. This statement gives an error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

VSCode suggests to convert `const utility = require('./utility');` to an ES6 module. The result after accepting that suggestion is: `import { generateRandomData } from './utility';`.

If I do this, the previous error goes away but a new error appears `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.

This is the folder structure of the project:

[image]

`server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("server started")
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')))

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
});
```

`utility.js`:

```
const hello = () => {
    console.log('hello');
}

module.exports.hello = hello;
```

How else am I supposed to import javascript files in `board.js`?

Comment: Express is irrelevent here since you are dealing with *client-side* JavaScript. The content of `board.js` is *not* irrelevent since you are trying to import there. The HTML that loads `board.js` into the HTML document is probably relevant too.

Comment: try module.exports = {hello};

Comment: @user2222 It did not resolve the error.

Comment: yes, i see it's obvious you can't use require in client side files,
Browsers don't have the require method defined, node js does.
try to use https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-browserify/ instead

Comment: could you please share your index.html and borad.js?

Comment: try  this <script type="module" src="board.js"></script>

Comment: I get this error - Loading module from “http://localhost:5000/utility” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

Comment: <script type="module" src="board.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Your *public* directory is made static via express.static in your server.js. Therefore, calling a *public* file from client-side will not pass by express but by the client's browser.

If your JS is played directly within a browser, instead of require you should use [import and export](https://alligator.io/js/modules-es6/).

Comment: import and export raised this error: SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: import is at top level, first line first character ? Nothing before, even space ?

Comment: Yes, it is the first line of the board.js file. There is no space before import.

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle link of board and utility.js ? Because the browser's console is wise usually. :)

Comment: I copied the code locally and made a utility.js file: I have no errors...

Comment: Lol what? Anyways I will try some different method... Thanks!

Comment: import is an es6 feature, it's not supported in all browsers, so to use it in browser you need to use a transpiler like babel https://babeljs.io/.

Comment: Modules are well supported now: https://caniuse.com/#search=modules (reminds me @echoaman, if you call the script from the client side, don't forget the module "type" in your <script>

Answer (score -2):

```
<script src="utility.js"></script>
```

I added this line in index.html and it solved the problem.

Edit: Sorry, I thought I pasted the line.

Comment: wich line you added?